# Java: how to count number of non repeated elements in an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays, int, duplicates

How do you **count the number of numbers** that occur in only **one of the two arrays**?

Example: countdifference([2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8], [3, 4, 6, 6, 9]) returns 4 because 4 and 6 are duplicates, remaining numbers are 2, 8, 3 and 9.

noOfRepeatsCount method is intended to account for repeated elements in arrayB: i.e. 6

I am getting an index array out of bounds exception: -1 for the noOfRepeatsCount method. Any ideas why?

```
public class countNonRepeated {

  static int countDifference(int[] arrayA, int[] arrayB) {
    int count = 0, repeatCount = 0, noOfRepeatsCount = 0;
    /*
    int noOfRepeats = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < arrayB.length; k++) {
      if (arrayB[k] == arrayB[k - 1]) {
        noOfRepeats++;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < arrayB.length; j++) {
        if (arrayA[i] == arrayB[j]) {
          if (arrayA[i + 1] == arrayB[j]) {
            repeatCount++;
          } else {
            count++;
          }
        } else {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
    int length = arrayA.length + arrayB.length;
    return length - (noOfRepeatsCount * repeatCount) - (count * 2);
  }

  static int noOfRepeatsCount(int[] arrayB) {
    int noOfRepeats = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < arrayB.length; k++) {
      if (arrayB[k] == arrayB[k - 1]) {
        noOfRepeats++;
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
    return noOfRepeats;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arrayA[] = { 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8 };
    int arrayB[] = { 3, 4, 6, 6, 9 };
    // System.out.println(noOfRepeatsCount(arrayA));
    System.out.println(countDifference(arrayA, arrayB));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the for loop in `noOfRepeatsCount` method. `if (arrayB[k] == arrayB[k - 1])` makes exception error. Because initial `k` value is 0, you access `arrayB[-1]`.

If you want to solve this problem, change `for (int k = 0; k < arrayB.length; k++)` to `for (int k = 1; k < arrayB.length; k++)`.

Answer (score 0):

What about converting the arrays to Sets and using a combination of removeAll(), addAll() and size() to get the desired result. I guess that this would make the algorithm clearer and avoid off-by-one errors.

I have no time right now to post a code sample, sorry.